# Most elegant way to make an XSD attribute accept two types (xs:string and xs:long)?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have received a specification for a SOAP service where the request that I'm sent will contain the following:

```
<eventContexts>
    <eventContext name="eventType" value="Unwind"/>
    <eventContext name="referenceId" value="26214"/>
</eventContexts>
```

I am trying to model this object in the XSD but I'm blocked in the choice of `type` for the attribute `value`. As you can see in the above example, it can either be a `xs:string` (case `Unwind`) or a `xs:long` (case `26214`).

What type should I choose to make the attribute `value` accept both `xs:string` and `xs:long`? 
So far I can think of two things:

1) Should I create two different attributes, e.g. `stringValue` and `longValue`:

```
<xs:complexType name="XmlEventContext">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>Sh
    <xs:attribute name="stringValue" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:attribute name="longValue" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0"/>   
</xs:complexType>
```

... and let the client send me the good value in the good attribute? (This looks ugly to me but I'm not a big expert).

2) Should I extend the auto-generated class `XmlEventContext` with a custom class that takes the `value` as `xs:string` and then tries to cast it to `xs:long`?

```
public class XmlEventContextComplete extends XmlEventContext {
    //code to manage a property referenceId which can either be long or string
}
```

3) Any other more elegant suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You want a type that can be either a `long` or a specific enumerated `string`.

This should cover that case:

```
<xs:complexType name="xmlEventContext">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="longOrUnwind" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="longOrUnwind">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:long unwindConstant" />
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="unwindConstant">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Unwind" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```